# c function getline includes the '\n' character

Tags: c, input, stdin, stdio

Is there a way to not get in my string the new line character when using `getline(&string, &len, stdin)`? Or someone know a way to get input from stdin?
I'm using C11 with the gcc compiler

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: @xing `getline` conveniently returns number of chars read, so there is no need to parse it again using `strcspn`

Comment: There are many ways to get input from stdin.

Comment: Note that POSIX defines [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), not one of the C standards.  Also note that `getline()` returns `-1` rather than `EOF` when EOF is detected.  Usually, that's the same value, but it is not guaranteed that `EOF == -1`.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own one:

```
ssize_t meygetline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, FILE *restrict stream)
{
    ssize_t result = getline(lineptr, n, stream);
    if(result > 0) 
        if((*lineptr)[result - 1] == '\n') {(*lineptr)[result - 1]= 0; result--;}
    return result;
}
```

Comment: the lenght of the string will be the same as the the one with the '\n'?

Comment: @Proth Yes, just the last `\n` will be replaced by a `\0`.

Comment: @Proth No, the length of the string with the `\n` removed will be one less than the length of the string that retains the `\n`.  If you remove a character from the end of a string, it's length decreases by 1.